# Enum int with string value in swift

Tags: swift, enums, pagination

I have enum of API endpoints which i use during the base url creation.
one of the API which has pagination is like ***pagination = "/api/pagination_test/%@?"***

Now during pagination i want to pass value to enum initalizer and create an enum which will be accepted by the base-url creation function.

```
enum APIEndPoints{
case registerUser = "/register"
case login = "/login"
case getData = "/data?"
case pagination = "/api/pagination_test/%@?"

}
func callPaginationAPI(pagenumber: Int){
//make enum with pagenumber, i am stuck in this line.
//let enum = 
//call main service method,pass enum as argument.
   mainService(endPoint: .pagination) 
// this expect an enum of pagination with proper pagenumber
}

func mainService(endpoint: APIEndpoints){
//create base url here
let url = requestUrl()
//do nsurlsession with prepared url
}

func requestUrl( endPoint: APIEndPoints) -> String {
    let baseURL = self.requestBaseUrl()
    return baseURL + endPoint.rawValue
}
```

How can i create a pagination enum with value one - am expecting enum as ***/api/pagination_test/1? , /api/pagination_test/2?***

Comment: Where does the pagination number come from?

Comment: Treat this same as login or register endpoint, the only difference will be that you have to append page number value to endpoint instead of putting it in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the enum should be update so we can use `String(format:)`

```
enum APIEndPoints: String {
    case registerUser = "/register"
    case login = "/login"
    case getData = "/data?"
    case pagination = "/api/pagination_test/%d?"
}
```

To avoid having to pass the page number as a parameter through all methods it is probably better to wrap the enum inside a struct together with the (optional) page number and have a computed property that gets the endpoint as a string

```
struct EndPoint {
    let apiEndPoint: APIEndPoints
    let page: Int?

    var endPointValue: String {
        switch apiEndPoint {
        case .pagination:
            return String(format: apiEndPoint.rawValue, page ?? 1)
        default:
            return apiEndPoint.rawValue
        }
    }

    init(_ endPoint: APIEndPoints, page: Int? = nil) {
        apiEndPoint = endPoint
        self.page = page
    }
}
```

And then pass an instance of this struct instead

```
func callPaginationAPI(pagenumber: Int){
    mainService(endpoint: EndPoint(.pagination, page: pagenumber))
}
```

And use the computed property when creating the url

```
func requestUrl(endPoint: EndPoint) -> String {
    let baseURL = self.requestBaseUrl()
    return baseURL + endPoint.endPointValue
}
```

And an example to use the struct without a page number

```
func callLoginAPI() {
    mainService(endpoint: EndPoint(.login))
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reponse. 
I need some more help with this.
my code flow is as follows.
//Call pagination API function
Where i want to mention the enum with pagenumber, This function inturn calls main service call 
// call main service call
inside this function i will create the url with endpoint.


With the given solution, i have to pass the pagenumber all way down to my main service call. How can i avoid it

Comment: I have edited the question.Please check.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It works. I wasn't thinking out of enum. Thanks you!.